# How to show traffics on Mapbox version 10 in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox-ios

```
  func showTraffic(mapView: MapView) {
            
    let sourceId = "mapbox-traffic-v1"

    var vectorSource = VectorSource()
    vectorSource.url = "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-traffic-v1"

    var trafficLayer = LineLayer(id: "traffic")

    // `visibility` is `nil` by default. Set to `visible`.
    trafficLayer.visibility = .constant(.visible)
    trafficLayer.lineColor = .constant(StyleColor(.red))
    trafficLayer.lineCap = .constant(.round)
    trafficLayer.lineJoin = .constant(.round)
    trafficLayer.lineWidth = .constant(5)


    let style = mapView.mapboxMap.style

    // Add the sources and layers to the map's style.
    do {
        try style.addSource(vectorSource, id: sourceId)
        try style.addLayer(trafficLayer)
    } catch {
        print("Error when adding sources and layers: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

I tried implementing this code, but nothing seems to happen. Do you have any ideas on how to display traffic on Mapbox?